# Is it possible to export safari's reading list on Safari 5.1?

Tags: safari

Subject sums it up. Just curious if there is a trick to be able to export your reading list from Safari, any format. Where on the HD is the info stored? bookmarks.plist?

Comment: I'll bet that once the iCloud drops, we'll see this sync between your computers automatically. Not sure if that was where you're going with this, but it's semi-related.

Comment: [I have this question for Safari on iOS.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143994/how-to-backup-and-access-ios-safaris-reading-list)

Answer (score 10):

You can convert it into XML in a Terminal/command window using:

```
cd ~/Library/Safari/
cp Bookmarks.plist Bookmarks.plist.xml  
plutil -convert xml1 Bookmarks.plist.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The file is called `Bookmarks.plist` and it is located in `~/Library/Safari/`. This houses not only your Reading List bookmarks, but all your bookmarks.

You'll want to look for entries under the key `ReadingList`. They will look something like this (file viewed in xCode 4):

[image]

Unfortunately, the plist file is stored as a binary, and you'll either have to open it using xCode or another tool that can handle binary plist files.

Answer (score 1):

You can't export from Safari but you can import from Chrome

Here it is on Google support: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en

Alternatively you can open the Terminal application on a Mac (search it in Launchpad if you can't find it) and paste this:

```
/usr/bin/plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist | grep -E  -o '<string>http[s]{0,1}://.*</string>' | grep -v icloud | sed -E 's/<\/{0,1}string>//g'
```

Hit return and it will list all your Reading List links as text which you can copy and paste elsewhere.

Comment: At some point this stopped working as intended. On Mojave it dumps all URLs in the file, not just the reading list.

Answer (score 0):

If you append ' > ~/Desktop/safariReading.rtf' to the Terminal line from above, you will get a rich-text format file on your Desktop.

This file contains the Safari Reading List & Bookmarks URLs in clickable format. The file could be used for archiving or for creating a project file with notes on what the URLs are for, etc.

```
/usr/bin/plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist | grep -E  -o '<string>http[s]{0,1}://.*</string>' | grep -v icloud | sed -E 's/<\/{0,1}string>//g' > ~/Desktop/safariReading.rtf
```

Comment: It’s helpful if you explain what the command actually does - it helps others understand how this works.

Answer (score -2):

In OS X Yosemite, go to ~/Library/Safari/ReadingListArchives