# Download reading list as csv

Tags: icloud, data-transfer, reading-list

I'm looking to download the reading list I've been populating from iOS (I think this is stored in iCloud), preferably in CSV format. Is this possible? I don't mind getting it in another format, but I'd prefer to get it from the web (I couldn't find iCloud's online interface, is that still a thing?) and not from iTunes.

Comment: Do you want to be able to download it remotely, or just find it locally on your computer? If you have it synched to your desktop, then I think [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24864/is-it-possible-to-export-safaris-reading-list-on-safari-5-1) has a good solution for the latter case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print the URLs of bookmarks and pages on the reading list:

`defaults read ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist|sed -n 's/^ *URLString = "\(.*\)";/\1/p'`

Print the URL, title, date added, and preview text for reading list items as CSV:

`sudo gem install plist csv;plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist|ruby -rplist -rcsv -e 'Plist.parse_xml(STDIN.read)["Children"].select{|e|e["Title"]=="com.apple.ReadingList"}[0]["Children"].each{|e|puts [e["URLString"],e["URIDictionary"]["title"],e["ReadingList"]["DateAdded"].strftime("%F %T"),e["ReadingList"]["PreviewText"]].to_csv}'`

Comment: The 'defaults' command was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: All of this is certainly very nice, but when you have already brought the file `.plist` on a Mac. I have my reading list on my iPhone. [How can I bring the reading list on a Mac, or on a PC ?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143994/how-to-backup-and-access-ios-safaris-reading-list)

Comment: many thanks for this nice answer and help this string does not work on the Mac Catalina 10.15 Traceback (most recent call last):
-e:1:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) ruby --version
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]

Comment: @azuranet I just tried the second command in Big Sur. Both the installation of the gems and the command itself worked. If it doesn't for you, please ask a new question with details, and link to the Q&A here for reference.

Comment: `defaults read ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist |sed -n 's/^ *URLString = "\(.*\)";/\1/p'`
Output: Domain /Users/user/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist does not exist